# Why is the L key used to confirm format?

Tags: windows, format

Just curious, when formatting a drive to install Windows. Why was the <kbd>L</kbd> key chosen as the confirm key?

Comment: Just to clarify the close reason, since you are a new user.  The problem is that the question calls for speculation.  No one except the program manager at microsoft who designed this feature could possibly answer your question.

Answer (score 5):

There are many people out there that just press "Enter" all the time when going through a wizard and don't read. This is to force the person to read the options, and help them make sure that this is really what they want to do.

It would be horrible for someone to try to "repair" the OS and accidentally format it...

[image: Example Screenshot of Occurrence]

Hope this help!

Answer (score 3):

Because of the unlikely event that someone will hit the L key on accident, and therefore formatting their disk.

Just a guess :)

Comment: Yea, I get why we wouldn't use enter.  Just was hoping there was some fun story about the L key

Comment: It's the most frequently used letter in 'Bill Gates'?